# Doesn't execute dynamic mysql query in nodejs

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am trying to execute a dynamic query needed for an api written using nodejs as server language and mysql as db. The query that i have written is a dynamic query and the query used UNION to join two queries. For some reason, it doesn't take the seconds conditions.where in the sql query and give the below error message.

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?) AND r.ReviewRating IN (?) AND r.Title IS NOT NULL AND r.DateCreated BETWEEN (' at line 1"
```

Below is the function in my modal class.:

```
 getReviewsAndPhotoReportBySellerId: (sellerId, reviewRating, title, photoAvailable, dateFrom, dateTo, callback) => {
    //Dynamic Query Generation based on user input
     function buildConditions() {
       var conditions = [];
       var values = [];

       if (typeof sellerId !== 'undefined') {
        conditions.push("r.SellerId IN (?)");
        values.push(sellerId);
       }
     
       if (typeof reviewRating !== 'undefined') {
         conditions.push("r.ReviewRating IN (?)");
         values.push(reviewRating);
       }
 
       if(title == "has comment"){
        conditions.push("r.Title IS NOT NULL");
       }else if(title == "no comment"){
        conditions.push("r.Title IS NULL");
       }

       if(photoAvailable == 1){
        conditions.push("rp.ReviewImageUrl1 IS NOT NULL || rp.ReviewImageUrl2 IS NOT NULL || rp.ReviewImageUrl3 IS NOT NULL");
       }else if(photoAvailable == 'undefined'){
        conditions.push("rp.ReviewImageUrl1 IS NULL && rp.ReviewImageUrl2 IS NULL && rp.ReviewImageUrl3 IS NULL");
       }

       if(typeof dateFrom !== 'undefined' && typeof dateTo !== 'undefined' ){
        conditions.push("r.DateCreated BETWEEN (?) AND (?) ");
        values.push(dateFrom);
        values.push(dateTo);
      }

       return {
         where: conditions.length ?
                  conditions.join(' AND ') : '1',
         values: values
       };
     }
     
     var conditions = buildConditions();

     var sql = 
     '(select *, r.ReviewId  AS ActualReviewId, r.DateCreated AS ActualDateCreated from review r LEFT join reviewphoto rp ON r.ReviewId = rp.ReviewId WHERE '  
     + conditions.where 
     + ') UNION ' 
     + '(select *, r.ReviewId  AS ActualReviewId, r.DateCreated AS ActualDateCreated from review r RIGHT join reviewphoto rp ON r.ReviewId = rp.ReviewId WHERE ' 
     + conditions.where 
     + ') ORDER BY ActualDateCreated DESC ';     
     console.log(sql);
     pool.query(sql, conditions.values,  (error, results, fields) => {
           if (error) {
             callback(error);
           }
           return callback(null, results);
         }
     );
   },
```

Comment: Can someone please reply this one or look at it. I am waiting for this one, as this could fix my long days of effort. I know this is a very minor fix which i am missing in mysql statement but dont know where is the fix.

Comment: Any update here from anyone please ?